# Contenido de un layout deslizable

Tags: android, xml, layout

Tengo un layout con bastantes botones mi idea es que aunque no se muestren todos a la vez si pueda desplazar de arriba a bajo el contenido de ese layout para poder navegar en el. Pero nose como puedo hacerlo... Alguna idea?? adjunto imagen y código.

[image: Situación]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="355dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Noticias" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Estado" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un [RecyclerView](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) si tienes vistas cargadas dentro de lo que quieres hacer Scroll.

Puedes hacer también un Listview en vez de crear tantos botones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="355dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvListaDeBotones"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Noticias" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Estado" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Crea esto en tu activity:

```
static final String[] TITULOS_BTN =
            new String[] { "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5"};

public ListView lvListaDeBotones;
```

Agrega este código en el onCreate o donde quieras inicializar tu listview asociado a la vista padre:

```
lvListaDeBotones = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvListaDeBotones);
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, TITULOS_BTN);
lvListaDeBotones.setAdapter(mAdapter);

lvListaDeBotones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Aquí puedes capturar en on Click de la vista que se crea en general.
            }
        });
```

Crea la vista para los items de tu `lisview`:

**listview_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Crea tu adaptador, que va a contener la vista hijo de tu `listview`:

Nota: no olvides agregar el `package` asociado:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_items, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
        Button btnAction = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
        btnAction.setText(values[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Para crear más botones, solo agrega titulos a tu arreglo de `String []`, saludos.

Si tu vista es muy grande y algunos botones no se ven, luego de agregar el lsitview, utiliza como padre un `<ScrollView> </ScrollView>` encima del primer `<RelativeLayout>` y si estas trabajando con API Level > 21, utiliza esta propiedad en el `<ListView>`  `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` para poder hacer scroll independientes.

Comment: me sirvio perfectamente tengo una pequeña duda los tamaños que le he dado a los layout he empleado medidas de tipo dp ya que no me deja usar porcentajes... ¿Afecta esto a si lo ejecuto en un movil o otro movil de mayor tamaño? a que no se a molde a cada pantalla me refiero

Comment: En la documentacion de Android acerca de soportar diferentes resoluciones y Material Design para Android encontrarás una buena información.

Comment: Tu respuesta me vino como anillo al dedo, te lo agradezco. Mi duda ahora es como puedo ingresar un id a cada uno de los botones o como pu do obtener el id de cada elemento para poder dar vida a los botones y poder realizar el método onClick de cada botón.

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta y te responderé. Solo hay que manejar los views con un holder y asignarle Tags.

Comment: oquei realizo un nuevo post